# 100 mbps network transfers slows down PC

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, file-transfer, gigabit-ethernet

We have a network with many PC's. There is a 1 gbps ethernet switch with 8 ports and a 100 mbps ethernet switch with 8 ports.

My PC is plugged into the 1 gbps switch. When someone on the network that is also plugged into the 1 gbps switch copies files from me, my PC is slowed down (slow and unresponsive) and I can feel it while working on my PC which is understandable.

I plugged in some people into the 100 mbps ethernet switch with the idea that when they copy large files from me that they won't slow down my PC. Unfortunately people copying files from me who are connected to the 100 mbps ethernet switch also slows down my PC. (Just like people copying much faster who are connected to the 1 gbps switch)

I find this really odd as my PC should not be slowed down because it is only giving out data at more or less 100 mbps over the network. Is this normal? I have an I7 with 16 Gigs of ram. The hard drives I'm using runs at a speed of 7200rpm. I'm using Windows 7.

Is there perhaps anything I can do to avoid people dragging down my PC (making my PC slow and unresponsive) when copying large files from me who are connected to the 100 mbps switch? (Logically my PC should not slow down in this situation)

**Update:**

Thanks to: ***Spiff* Jul 16 '15 at 18:01 below.** I disabled flow control on the ethernet card of my PC and the problem is solved. Thanks *Spiff*!

Comment: Check that your hard disk is in good shape by evaluating the SMART stats. A dying (or overfull) disk would explain your issue.

Comment: Are these two switches normally connected to one another in some capacity?

Comment: Looks like a hard drive error. Maybe an ssd would help

Comment: You've got a subject/verb agreement (singular vs. plural) problem in your sentence about hard drives, so I can't tell if you have just one drive, or multiple drives. This might not be a network problem at all, if the files you're serving to others are on the same physical HDD as your swap and system files. The fact that your drive is 7200 RPM is no guarantee that it's not still a disk I/O problem.

Comment: Another thought: Make sure you're not doing Ethernet flow-control on your server's gigabit port or on the gigabit switch. If you're running into Head-of-Line Blocking problems, it could be slowing your PC's network access, and with the amount that network/Internet work is involved in modern PC usage, slow network/Internet access can make the PC feel generally slow.

Comment: The 2 switches are connected to each other. I have 1 SSD drive and 2 4tb 7200rpm hard drives in my pc. The files that are copied are on the 4tb  drives. I don't believe there is something wrong with the drives. The PC is 100% fine but when someone starts copying large files the PC gets non-responsive and slow. Perhaps it has something to do with Windows 7 or some network setting in Windows 7.

Comment: Let's try to separate the Network and HDD issues. On your computer, if you copy a large file between those 2 4TB HDDs, do you experience the same slow down/unresponsive symptoms?

Comment: Copying files between the two 4tb HDDs does not create a slow-down. (Not as noticeably as when someone brings my PC to its knees when files are copied from me)